# How to embed or call HTML pages from Javascript in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make an Grid app in Visual Studio 2012, and for that I want to start with a separate home.html file instead with default.html page. With in home.html I have used a small description Paragraph where I wish to link some text (words) to other pages in Apps. How to link those pages?

I have used the content description within a variable like

```
var groupDIntro = " This is introduction page. We will start with some programming";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your description in a paragraph, and wrap the links in `a` tags. Something like this:

```
<p>
    This is an <a href="/intro">introduction</a> page. We will start with some <a href="/programming">programming</a>.
</p>
```

And it will be rendered in the HTML file as:

This is an [introduction](/intro) page. We will start with some [programming](/programming)

Answer (score 0):

you have two options, 
you can use frame to link content to any page and view it embedded 
or you can use ajax function in jquery

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('div.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```